# Horizontal text scroller with length detection javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroller

I am looking for a way to do Horizontal text scrolling that only scrolls ONLY WHEN the text length is longer than the container DIV. Any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: I need the text to be automatically scrolling too, just like a "stock ticker" on CNN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

CSS

```
.container { width: 600px; background: #ccc; }
.ticker { white-space: nowrap; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<span class="ticker">Some short text that isn't greater than the browser window</span>
<span class="ticker">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed facilisis metus quis augue facilisis elementum. Pellentesque aliquet congue tristique. Phasellus feugiat cursus lobortis. Cras et massa odio, et vehicula nisi. Donec adipiscing condimentum diam sed hendrerit. Curabitur eros elit, aliquet et aliquam id, facilisis id nisi. Vivamus dictum commodo libero, eu venenatis nulla sodales in. Maecenas rhoncus, dui at sollicitudin scelerisque, neque lectus viverra metus, vel elementum nisl ante quis mi. Cras sagittis enim ac arcu scelerisque tristique vel in dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras vehicula leo vel lacus blandit ut adipiscing lorem sodales.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed facilisis metus quis augue facilisis elementum. Pellentesque aliquet congue tristique. Phasellus feugiat cursus lobortis. Cras et massa odio, et vehicula nisi. Donec adipiscing condimentum diam sed hendrerit. Curabitur eros elit, aliquet et aliquam id, facilisis id nisi. Vivamus dictum commodo libero, eu venenatis nulla sodales in. Maecenas rhoncus, dui at sollicitudin scelerisque, neque lectus viverra metus, vel elementum nisl ante quis mi. Cras sagittis enim ac arcu scelerisque tristique vel in dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras vehicula leo vel lacus blandit ut adipiscing lorem sodales. Vestibulum ultricies elementum mattis. Maecenas sit amet turpis magna. Phasellus posuere mi nec nisi sodales non dapibus nibh faucibus. Vestibulum leo tellus, blandit sed auctor id, faucibus quis sem. Sed at purus quam. Praesent eget ante sem, a scelerisque nulla. Praesent id quam sit amet eros viverra euismod. Integer volutpat vulputate aliquam. Aliquam convallis dolor tellus, in cursus justo. Donec molestie consequat dolor. Nunc imperdiet arcu et justo vehicula mollis. Suspendisse id molestie velit. Morbi sed est arcu, non aliquam augue.</span>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var tickerWidth = '100%'; // add '%' or 'px' to this variable
 var tickerSpeed = 10; // 0 = stopped, 30 = almost too fast
 var tickerDelay = 0; // delay in ms
 var tickerDirection = 'left'; // options = left, right (up & down work as well, but not the way you want)
 var tickerMouseoverPause = true;
 var tickerLoopTimes = 0; // 0 = infinite # of loops

 $('.ticker').each(function(){
  if ( $(this).width() >  $(this).parent().width() ) {
   var marq = $('<marquee></marquee>').attr({
    'behavior' : 'scroll',
    'scrollamount' : tickerSpeed,
    'direction' : tickerDirection,
    'width' : tickerWidth
   })
   if (tickerLoopTimes != 0) {
    marq.attr('loop', tickerLoopTimes) 
   }
   if (tickerMouseoverPause) {
    marq.attr({
     'onmouseover' : 'this.stop()',
     'onmouseout' : 'this.start()'
    })
   }
   $(this).wrap(marq);
  }
 })
})
```

This script basically wraps the text with a `<marquee>`, to get more information on it's attributes check out [this site](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_marquee_code.cfm).

*NOTE* I tried using unobtrusive jQuery for this, using `hover` over the marquee, but it doesn't work. But adding inline `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to the tag works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice one

[JavaScript Bs_ScrollableDiv](http://www.blueshoes.org/_bsJavascript/components/scrollablediv/examples/example2.html)

Comment: can it be automatically scrolling too, just like a "stock ticker" on CNN?

Comment: Just something simple.. no need to have tons of js code or heavy plugin